# Bitcoin-qt falls behind on blockchain, how to replace?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

On Apple Mac, bitcoin-qt is 14 days behind. Never approaches current time. Have downloaded current blockchain from trusted source. Where to install? What procedure?

Comment: Has it stopped downloading entirely (even after leaving it on for several hours), or does it just lag behind?

Comment: Will never catch up. For 2 weeks was behind 7-9 days, then 11 days just last week, and now 14 days behind.

Comment: My question is: does it still make progress? Are blocks (very slowly) coming in, or not?

Answer (score 2):

I know that there is a torrent where you can download the blockchain to jumpstart your fresh installation. This should also help to update your local wallet. In order to download and import the blockchain manually have a look at the instructions and the download link in this bitcointalk thread:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145386.0